# Change material on GameObjects with Unet in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject, unity3d-unet

I want to change the material of a GameObject on all clients when I click on it in any client. I am new to UNET and I assume I have a conceptional flaw. So basically what I am trying to do is:

1. Shoot a ray on the NetworkPlayer to an object in the scene
2. Send a `[Command]` from the player
3. In this `[Command]` call an `[ClientRpc]` on the object
4. In the `[ClientRpc]`change the material of this object

My player:

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

// This script is on my Game Player Prefab
// (removed the cam movement part)
public class CamMovement : NetworkBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        if (!isLocalPlayer)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
                CmdNextColor(hit.transform.gameObject);
        } 
    }

    [Command]
    public void CmdNextColor(GameObject hitObject)
    {
        RPC_ColorChange colorChange = hitObject.GetComponent<RPC_ColorChange>();
        if (colorChange != null)
        {
            colorChange.RpcNextColor();
        }
    }
}
```

My object:

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class RPC_ColorChange : NetworkBehaviour {

    public Material[] material;
    [SyncVar]
    int curColOfThisObject;
    Text text;

    private void Start()
    {
        text = GetComponentInChildren<Text>();
    }


    [ClientRpc]
    public void RpcNextColor()
    {
        if (!isClient)
            return;

        if (material.Length > 0)
        {
            Material curMaterial = this.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material;

            curColOfThisObject++;
            if (curColOfThisObject >= material.Length)
                curColOfThisObject = 0;

            curMaterial = material[curColOfThisObject];
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (isClient)
        {
            text.text = "new color of this object: " + curColOfThisObject.ToString();
        }
    }

}
```

What happens is:
The text on the object changes to the appropriate color, but the material is never changed. How do I change the material?

Bonus question:
If anyone knows a good tutorial on how to concept a UNET game please let me know.

Comment: Try editing [sharedMaterial](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-sharedMaterial.html)

Comment: @MassimoFrasson No! This would change the material for **all** objects using this material.

Comment: @derHugo you are right! Sorry! Anyway, can you upload your full project anywhere?

Comment: @MassimoFrasson not here but e.g. using [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/) or something comparable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you calculate the value of `curColOfThisObject` on the client side but at the same time use `[SyncVar]` for it.

From the [`[SyncVar]` Docu](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.SyncVarAttribute.html):

> These variables will have their values sychronized **from the server to clients**

-> Don't change the Values **on the clients** in `RpcNextColor` but rather already **on the server** in the `CmdNextColor`. Otherwise `curColOfThisObject` will instantly get overwritten with the deafult value which was never changed on the server. I would than pass the value to the clients as parameter in the `[ClientRpc]` so technically you wouldn't even need the `[SyncVar]` at all.

In `CamMovement`

```c#
[Command]
public void CmdNextColor(GameObject hitObject)
{
    RPC_ColorChange colorChange = hitObject.GetComponent<RPC_ColorChange>();
    if (colorChange != null)
    {
        colorChange.NextColor();
        // after calculating a new curColOfThisObject send it to clients (doesn't require [SyncVar] anymore)
        colorChange.RpcNextColor(curColOfThisObject);
    }
}
```

In `RPC_ColorChange`

```c#
// Make the calculation of the value on the server side
[Server]
private void NextColor()
{
    if (material.Length > 0)
    {
        Material curMaterial = this.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material;

        curColOfThisObject++;
        if (curColOfThisObject >= material.Length)
            curColOfThisObject = 0;

        // set the material also on the server
        curMaterial = material[curColOfThisObject];
    }
}

[ClientRpc]
public void RpcNextColor(int newValue)
{
    if (!isClient) return;

    // easier to debug if you keep the curColOfThisObject variable
    curColOfThisObject = newValue;

    if(newValue=> material.Length)
    {
        Debug.LogError("index not found in material");
        return;
    }

    // instead of curColOfThisObject  you could also just use the newValue
    // but this is easier to debug
    curMaterial = material[curColOfThisObject];
}
```

---

If you want to stick to the `[SyncVar]` you could also completely skip the `ClientRpc` and make it a `hook` for the `[SyncVar]` instead:

In `CamMovement`

```c#
[Command]
public void CmdNextColor(GameObject hitObject)
{
    RPC_ColorChange colorChange = hitObject.GetComponent<RPC_ColorChange>();
    if (colorChange != null)
    {
        colorChange.NextColor();
    }
}
```

In `RPC_ColorChange`

```c#
[SyncVar(hook = "OnNextColor")]
private int curColOfThisObject;

// Make the calculation of the value on the server side
[Server]
private void NextColor()
{
    if (material.Length > 0)
    {
        Material curMaterial = this.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material;

        curColOfThisObject++;
        if (curColOfThisObject >= material.Length)
            curColOfThisObject = 0;

        // set the material also on the server
        curMaterial = material[curColOfThisObject];
    }
}

// This method automatically gets called when the value of
// curColOfObject is changed to newValue on the server
private void OnNextColor(int newValue)
{
    if (!isClient) return;

    // easier to debug if you keep the curColOfThisObject  variable
    curColOfThisObject = newValue;

    if(newValue=> material.Length)
    {
        Debug.LogError("index not found in material");
        return;
    }

    // instead of curColOfThisObject  you could also just use the newValue
    // but this is easier to debug
    curMaterial = material[curColOfThisObject];
}
```

---

Little extra: I would check the existence of the `RPC_ColorChange` component **before** I send stuff through the network.

```c#
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
    {
        if(hit.GetComponent<RPC_ColorChange>()!=null)
        {
            CmdNextColor(hit.transform.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Be aware that you might hit a child or parent instead of the actual object you would like to hit .. so evtl. you'll have to look for the `RPC_ColorChange` component in the childs or parent using `GetComponentInChildren` or `GetComponentInParent`.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit counter-intuitive that RpcFunctions get invoked after the Command functions have been processed:

On the player prefab:

```
[Command]
    public void CmdNextColor(GameObject hitObject)
    {
        RPC_ColorChange colorChange = hitObject.GetComponent<RPC_ColorChange>();
        if (colorChange != null)
        {
            int curColor = colorChange.GetCurColor();

            // change color +1 on the clients
            colorChange.RpcNextColor(curColor);

            // assign a SyncVar with the current color
            colorChange.SyncColorVar();
        }
    }
```

Now the functions are called in the following order: 
1) SyncColorVar() 
2) RpcNextColor()

Test project: [gitlab.com/KlausUllrich/networkTest](http://gitlab.com/KlausUllrich/networkTest)